# Can Redux cause the React warning "Cannot update a component while rendering a different component"

Tags: reactjs, redux

The React warning "Cannot update a component while rendering a different component" was added to ver 16.13.0 of React. The cause of the warning can be somewhat difficult to trace.

The [React blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html#new-warnings) states:

> A React component should not cause side effects in other components during rendering.
> It is supported to call setState during render, but only for the same component.

The question is, can Redux cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you make a mistake. I wrote a Redux thunk action (an async action) that sometimes would find the needed data in cache right away and dispatch an action event during that render. Sometimes this action would update state that was used on many pages. This caused the warning.

A part of the state

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'data',
    initialState: {
        /** Base data from server */
        baseData: null,

        // === Place page ===

        /** Fetching status for place data */
        placeDataFetchStatus: FetchStatus.NOT_STARTED,
        ...
```

Here I'm fetching data for the component PlacePage during its render

```
function PlacePage(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {place_uri, area_uri, place_type_uri} = useParams();

    dispatch(fetchPlacePageData(place_uri, area_uri, place_type_uri));
```

This async action caused the warning

```
export const fetchPlacePageData = (place_uri, area_uri, place_type_uri) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    DataFetcher.implFetchPlacePageData(dispatch, getState, place_uri, area_uri, place_type_uri);
};


export const implFetchPlacePageData = (dispatch, getState, reqPlaceInfo, place_uri, area_uri, place_type_uri) => {
    ...

    // check if data is in cache
    const data = PlacePageDataCache.getData(id);
    if (data) {
        # The base data is used on many pages, this dispatch causes the warning 
        dispatch(set_base_data(data.base_data));

        dispatch(set_all_place_data(data.place_data));
        return;
    }
```

This is the stack trace from the browser console log:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing such a detailed answer to your question.  This will be helpful to others with similar problems!